# TargetInvocationException on token cancellation

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I would like to create a task running on a separate thread (non-GUI thread). The code seems to be working well but I can not get the cancellation logic to work.

[image]

I have a `Run` button and `Cancell` button in `GUI`. Whener I cancel the token - I get a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`. `InnerMessage` says the the `operation is cancelled` and I personally have no problems with that :)

Is this exception something I should worry about? How should I handle it? I tried putting `try`-`catch` blocks but they don't catch it..

Using `VS2015`. Some settings:

[image]

Code:

```
    public CancellationTokenSource ts;

    private async void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DoWork2();
    }

    public async Task DoWork2()
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Started!");

        ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;

        await Task.Run(() => // async
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Thread.Sleep(200);
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

        }, ct);

        ts.Cancel();

        textBox1.AppendText("Done!");
    }

    private void button28_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ts.Cancel();
    }
```

**EDIT: I was able to resolve the issue on above mentioned code! Added `OperationCancelledException` catch block inside the task. Now the exception is not thrown for code above. This is not the case for code below.**

My program is, however, much more complicatd than that. I get the same kind of exception for the code similar (but still simplified) to my original program:**

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list1.Add(i);
        }

        await Task.Run(() => // async
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(list1, int2 =>
                    {
                        // {Cancellation Pending}
                        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)// (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {

            }
        }, ct);
```

As you can see - I have parallel loops inside the task. This must be the problem. Even catch block doesn't help in this scenario. Any ideas?

**EDIT2: Okay, I was able to fix the second problem as well.** [nice tutorial from `Microsoft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
      ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
      po.CancellationToken = ts.Token;
```

and inside loop:

```
                while (true)
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(list1, po, int2 =>
                    {
                       // {Cancellation Pending}
                        po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    });
                }
```

Sorry the issue is now resolved but maybe somebody wants to leave any comments or blame me for the approach I have taken - I will close this question if no comments follow